# Arranging ggplot legend by groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way of arranging the ggplot legend by groups?

If I try:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars_tbl <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "make_model") %>%
  as_tibble %>% 
  mutate(point_col = case_when(cyl == 4 ~ "#009E73",
                               cyl == 6 ~ "#0072B2",
                               cyl == 8 ~ "#D55E00"))
cols_tbl <- mtcars_tbl %>% 
  select(make_model, point_col) %>% 
  deframe

mtcars_tbl %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = qsec, col = make_model)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols_tbl) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

The `make_model` comes out arranged alphabetically. I can specify the number of rows or columns or even change `make_model` to factor but what I'd like is the way they are arranged in the picture below (**importantly I want to have an uneven number of items**).

[image]

Comment: That's effecvtively a multi-variate aesthetic grouping, which I would love to see but have run into similar road-blocks. There has been some work in [`ggh4x`](https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x), perhaps that's a start for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of the `ggnewscale` package which allows for multiple color scales. One drawback of this approach is that it requires plotting your data via multiple `geom` layers too. In my approach below I first split the data as well as the color vectors by groups. To get the order of the groups right it's best make use of the `order` argument of `guide_legend`. Additionally I make use of the `title.theme` argument to "remove" the duplicated legend titles. Finally I use `theme` options to align the guides vertically and to the left.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggnewscale)

mtcars_tbl <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "make_model") %>%
  as_tibble %>% 
  mutate(point_col = case_when(cyl == 4 ~ "#009E73",
                               cyl == 6 ~ "#0072B2",
                               cyl == 8 ~ "#D55E00"))
cols_tbl <- mtcars_tbl %>% 
  select(make_model, point_col) %>% 
  deframe()

mtcars_tbl <- split(mtcars_tbl, mtcars_tbl$cyl)
cols_tbl <- lapply(mtcars_tbl, function(x) x %>% select(make_model, point_col) %>% deframe())

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = hp, y = qsec)) +
  geom_point(data = mtcars_tbl$`4`, aes(col = make_model)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols_tbl$`4`, 
                      guide = guide_legend(order = 1, title.theme = element_text(color = NA))) +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(data = mtcars_tbl$`6`, aes(col = make_model)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols_tbl$`6`,
                      guide = guide_legend(order = 2, title.theme = element_text(color = "black"))) +
  new_scale_color()+
  geom_point(data = mtcars_tbl$`8`, aes(col = make_model)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols_tbl$`8`,
                      guide = guide_legend(order = 3, title.theme = element_text(color = NA))) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.box = "vertical",
        legend.box.just = "left")
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent and exactly solved the problem I was looking for. Out of curiosity, is there a good way to add a "main" legend title, and then have titles for each of the  new_scale_color() sections? In the above example, that would be a main title of "Engine Cylinders" and then subtitles for 4, 6, and 8.

Comment: Hi @AlexKrohn. AFAIK there is no easy option to add a main title while having section titles too. In general you have to add the main title as some kind of annotation. To this end see e.g. [Add total number to ggplot legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72556876/add-total-number-to-ggplot-legend/72557229#72557229) for some options including an answer by me which makes use of `cowplot` and `patchwork` which would be my way to do it.